# Books/resources that teach software developers how to pragmatically use project/bug/task tracking tools

Tags: jira, project-management

Does anyone know of excellent (in your opinion) books/websites that go over in details how to pragmatically use a bug/task/project management tool to help improve software development process? Ideally, I would like "from-the-trench" kind of resource, not theory.

Examples of such mgmt tools are: JIRA/Confluence combo, Visual Studio Team System / Sharepoint, FogBugz, etc.

I think I'm looking for books that are like the 3 Pragmatic book series (source control, unit testing, and build automation) Come to think of it, I wish the pragmatic guys also released a book on how to integrate project mgmt tools to their software development process.

I know of a few that might fit as the answers to my question:

Painless Project Management with FogBugz, Second Edition
Visual Studio Team System: Better Software Development for Agile Teams
Software Engineering with Microsoft Visual Studio Team System

Much like how we learn different programming languages to broaden our thought process, I dont really mind what tool the book/website uses. What I'm most interested in is HOW the tool is integrated into software development process to help improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Steve McConnells' book [Rapid Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556159005)

Have you also looked at these books in the Pragmatic Bookshelf:

[Manage It!: Your Guide to Modern, Pragmatic Project Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739248)

[Ship it! A Practical Guide to Successful Software Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514047)

[Release It!: Design and Deploy Production-Ready Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739213)

Comment: thanks mitch. I ought to buy those books you mentioned to try them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "from the trenches" it's hard to beat [Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa740411.aspx).  They give you a chance to get hands-on with the technology (VSTS in this case).  There are VSTS labs on change management, managing development efforts, version control and etc.